# How do I run a Lein project in Clojure's new CLI tools version?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a Clojure project I started a couple of years ago.

It's all using Leiningen. With a project.clj file etc. And my code in src/myproj/blah.clj etc.

I now want to try using Clojure's new CLI tools.

I tried navigating into the root of this project directory and launching clj then typing (require '[myproj.blah :as blah])

But this throws a FileNotFoundException.

Can the CLI tools find code in a lein type file-structure and work with existing lein projects?

If not what's the procedure to adapt a lein project to use CLI tools?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guide to the new command line tools https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli

You need a `deps.edn` file that contains your dependencies instead of a `project.clj` file.

Here's some rationale of what deps does and doesn't do:
http://cdn.cognitect.com/presentations/2017/dependency_heaven.pdf